# How to alert the user when their password or email is wrong on ionic 3?

Tags: javascript, typescript, ionic3

I'm trying to create a check with showAlert to notify the user when they put the wrong email or password, but I'm not able to do with try and catch

Is it possible for me to do this with try and catch?

Here's the example of my login.ts code

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPage, NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';
import { User } from '../../models/user';
import { AngularFireAuth } from "angularfire2/auth";
import { MenuController } from "ionic-angular";
import { AlertController } from "ionic-angular";

@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'page-login',
  templateUrl: 'login.html',
})
export class LoginPage {

  user = {} as User;

  constructor(private afAuth: AngularFireAuth, public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams, public menu: MenuController, public alertCtrl: AlertController) {
  }

ionViewWillEnter(){
  this.menu.enable(false);
}

 async login(user: User){
  try{
    const result = await this.afAuth.auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(user.email, user.password);
    if (result) {
      this.navCtrl.setRoot('HomePage');
    }
  }
  catch {
    showAlert() {
      const alert = this.alertCtrl.create({
        title: 'New Friend!',
        subTitle: 'Your friend, Obi wan Kenobi, just accepted your friend request!',
        buttons: ['OK']
      });
      alert.present();
    }
  }

 }

 register(){
   this.navCtrl.push('RegisterPage');
 }

}
```

Comment: What problem are you currently having?

Comment: Sorry if my question was not very clear, but I want the user to be alerted when he put the wrong user or password

Comment: I mean, what goes wrong with the code you posted?

Comment: My function is not working inside the catch

Comment: You shouldn't be trying to define a method inside of another method.  If you just want to show the alert in the catch block, delete the `showAlert() {` and matching `}`, leaving the code that was inside.  If you also want to call this method from elsewhere, then move it outside of `login` and call it as `this.showAlert();`.

Comment: Yes, I followed this method and I got it, if you want to put it as an answer to get a score, please feel free to!

Answer (score 0):

I have decided as follows

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPage, NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';
import { User } from '../../models/user';
import { AngularFireAuth } from "angularfire2/auth";
import { MenuController } from "ionic-angular";
import { AlertController } from "ionic-angular";

@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'page-login',
  templateUrl: 'login.html',
})
export class LoginPage {

  user = {} as User;

  constructor(private afAuth: AngularFireAuth, public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams, public menu: MenuController, public alertCtrl: AlertController) {

  }

  showAlert() {
    const alert = this.alertCtrl.create({
      title: 'Atenção',
      subTitle: 'Seu e-mail ou senha estão incorretos, por favor tente novamente.',
      buttons: ['OK']
    });
    alert.present();
  }

  ionViewWillEnter(){
    this.menu.enable(false);
  }

 async login(user: User){
  try{
    const result = await this.afAuth.auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(user.email, user.password);
    if (result) {
      this.navCtrl.setRoot('HomePage');
    }
  }
  catch {
    this.showAlert();
  }

 }

 register(){
   this.navCtrl.push('RegisterPage');
 }

}
```